# C# Using Control.Tag Property vs. Class : Panel, for holding/referencing Panel Data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an WinFormApp that uses many Panels. I need to attach some varying information to the Panels.
 I made an "ItemClass" that has all my needed properties (Id, Type, etc..) the properties are mostly strings and integers.
I've been calling an instance of the ItemClass and attaching it to the Panel.Tag, and then Casting it, in later functions, to get the info.
Is it better practice (performance) to just create the Panel using a New Class for example:
 Class PanelClass : Panel { }
 and then set the info directly as Class Properties (Id, Type, etc.) ?
I will make about 100-300 Panels in this application.

Comment: Tag is a VB6 compat property, meant to help VB6 programmers port their program to .NET a decade ago.  Still using it makes very little sense, .NET support inheritance very well.  Just derive your own class from Panel, add the properties you need.

Comment: @Hans Thanks. Are there any downsides to calling Class with Control?
ie.. PanelClass : Panel { }  instead of just creating a new Panel() and attaching PanelClass { }

Comment: There are no down-sides.  "Attaching" is a meaningless word.

Comment: @Hans Thanks again,when i wrote "attach" i meant calling a new Panel().. for example PanelA = new Panel(); and then making a PanelClass1 with a construct that takes Panel as a Param. For Ex:
 [PanelClass1 PC1 = new PanelClass1(PanelA);]  and then setting Properties to the Panel thru the PanelClass1.. instead of creating a PanelClass2 : Panel which automatically create a Panel and allows to set Properties